# Searching for questions closed as off-topic

Tags: support, search, closed-questions

I want to find questions that were closed because they were off-topic.  So far the best I have been able to do is to search for [closed:1 duplicate:no](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+closed%3A1+duplicate%3Ano) which finds questions that were closed, but not for being duplicates.  Most of these seem to be "unclear what you are asking", and there does not seem to be any way to tell what the closure reason was  without opening the individual pages. I can see the question titles, but very few are obviously off-topic.

Is there some way to find off-topic questions more efficiently?

Comment: I don't think that the search engine is so refined. Perhaps using data.SE to search for questions closed as Off Topic is a more viable method.

Comment: I would note the distinction between questions that were closed as off-topic because they were actually off-topic, and questions that were closed as off-topic because people felt they deserved to be closed but didn't have a more accurate voting option.

Comment: @Gerry: Maybe it's possible to make that sort of distinction. But I'm not sure?

Answer (score 2):

[There you go.](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/229460/posts-closed-as-off-topic) There are some duplicates that I wasn't able to make go away -- my SQL skills aren't as good as they used to be.

Comment: Thanks very much!  I tinkered with SEDE yesterday but didn't find the posthistory table that is needed.  Your answer is very instructive.